# How do you configure Webpacker to work with a Rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm trying to configure Webpacker to work with a Rails engine. I'm specifically interested in how people are setting up their `webpacker.yml` to move their engine's assets to the main app's `/public/` folder.

First, I've followed the Webpacker instructions for [Using in Rails Engines](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/engines.md). However, Step 7 stumps me. The idea here is to set the `public_root_path` to your app's `/public` folder. I could obviously hard-code the correct path on my personal machine, but that's unsustainable for production or other devs. I [can't rely on ERB](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1615) to have a dynamic path either.

I also tried the [second option](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/engines.md#use-a-separate-middleware) of Step 7 which involves middleware, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

I ultimately want to be able to import JavaScript from the engine into the main app from the `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file. How do I get Webpacker to *find* the files from the engine without hard-coding the path?